# Selecting nodes with different classes in XPath in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

I'm attempting to use XPath to select nodes that have different classes. Only two, in this case. One is "msg_head" and the other is "msg_sub_head".

The following is currently the string I'm running with after many hours of Googling and searching here on Stack Overflow. I feel I'm close, but not quite there.

```
//*[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' msg_head') and (contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' msg_sub_head'))]
```

Comment: Works fine here http://codepad.viper-7.com/foOHQm though I'd add trailing spaces to your search strings, for example `' msg_head '` instead of `' msg_head'`

Comment: This was the issue. It's always the little things. Thanks, Phil!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're just missing the spaces at the end of your `contains` *search* argument. For example, where you have `' msg_head'`, you actually want `' msg_head '`.